# set for how long showErrorMessage() is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying my error messages like this:

```
showErrorMessage("Description and Measure fields cant be empty");
```

The problem is it doesn't stay long enough for people to read the message. So how am I supposed to make it last longer?

here is the function in which am using it `

```
    function addGoal()  {

    var description = $('.description').val();
    var measure = $('.measure').val();
if((description!="")&&(measure!="")){
//do some thing
}else {
showErrorMessage("Description and Measure fields cant be empty");
}
```

`

sorry here is my function

```
function showErrorMessage(message){
        noty({
            text: message,
            type: "error",
            theme: "gmailTheme",
            layout: "topCenter",
           });
    }
```

Comment: which technology you are talking about?

Comment: We need to see the code in your `showErrorMessage()` function to be of any help. At the moment this question is completely un-answerable.

Comment: Please add context so the question is comprehensible.

Comment: `showErrorMessage()` can you post your function?

Answer (score 0):

> timeout: false, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications